# Docker refuses to execute commands or start containers with Ubuntu 20 image on Ubuntu 21 host, but works on Ubuntu 20 host

Tags: docker, ubuntu

So I've pulled the amd64/ubuntu:latest image, which is an Ubuntu 20 image for docker and customized it a bit. Not much - zsh, vim, locales and openssh-server compiled from source (because the package wants me to download 100Mb of some stuff, whereas the compiled version is only 1.5 Mb)

In this case, I don't think those are the reason for the following problem: I did not intend to use Dockerfiles with this one, and I created and ran containers with the following command:

```
$ docker run -dit --network=my_docker_network --name=MyContainer \
  local/ubuntu:latest
```

This works fine on my Ubuntu 20.04 - notice how there isn't a command after the image name, which, as per documentation, is supposed to be there, but it looks like it isn't needed here. The `sshd` is later started manually by the `docker exec` command and works fine.

Now, to test the compatibility, I've installed Ubuntu 21 on a VirtualBox, then installed docker there and imported my custom image `local/ubuntu:latest`. Docker versions and the way they are run seem to be exactly the same - v20.10.12. When I run the same `docker run...` command on Ubuntu 21, it refuses to start start the image, saying another argument - the COMMAND - is require. Yet when I provide ANY command as the last argument, for example:

```
$ docker run -dit --network=my_docker_network --name=MyContainer \
  local/ubuntu:latest /usr/bin/sh -c 'echo OK'
```

or

```
$ docker run -dit --network=my_docker_network --name=MyContainer \
  local/ubuntu:latest /usr/bin/sshd
```

it says they're not in $PATH or file doesn't exist.

If I try and create a container first, it is indeed created with:

```
$ docker create -it --network=my_docker_network --name=MyContainer \
  local/ubuntu:latest
```

But the same problem occurs once I try actually starting it. What is this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked on the Docker forums - apparently to correctly "import" the image, you don't user the `import` command but instead user `image load` command.

INCORRECT:

```
$ docker image save local/ubuntu:latest -o ubuntu.tgz # on Ubuntu 20
$ docker import ubuntu.tgz local/ubuntu:latest        # WRONG! on Ubuntu 21
```

**CORRECT:**

```
$ docker image save local/ubuntu:latest -o ubuntu.tgz # on Ubuntu 20
$ docker image load -i ubuntu.tgz                     # on Ubuntu 21
```

Credits go to the person who [answered this question](https://forums.docker.com/t/same-image-refuses-to-run-on-ubuntu-21-but-runs-on-ubuntu-20-docker-versions-are-the-same/121955) on the Docker forum here. Also note, that if you run `docker image save` the image full name (`repo/name:tag`) is actually save with along with other information, so upon running `docker image load -i ubuntu.tgz` Docker will tag that image as exactly as it was tagged when it was saved. If an image with the same name exists, it will be replaced, so be careful.